# Python [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, path, xls

I'm trying to iterate over a folder containing only xls files and to open them one by one. Note: all the xsl files are enumerate like "001_text.xls", ... "030_text.xls".

My code is:

```
xls_path=r'C:\path\to\my\folder'

for file in os.listdir(xls_path):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

    filt_xls = [ el for el in sheet.col_values(0)]

    print file.title()
    print filt_xls
```

The problem is that i get the output only for the first file (001_text.xls) and consecutively the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '002_Testo.xls'
```

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: The folder should contain only xls files. The files `002_Testo` with any kind of extension could cause Error because of that -i guess- `xlrd.open_workbook(file)` add `.xls` extension to the `file`.

Comment: Is there such  a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably forgotten to add a directory name to each file path

```
import os.path

for file in os.listdir(xls_path):
    file = os.path.join(xls_path, file)
    .....
```